# Cordova backbutton event not working even with preventDefault action

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

I am using Cordova 11.1.0 to build an android app. I am trying to override the backbutton event to ignore the action completely so that it doesn't go back to the previous page.

This the code I am using:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    function onBackKeyDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Back Button is Pressed!');
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I built the app and installed it on my phone to check but it still goes back to the previous page and I don't see the alert too. Kindly help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to wait for the `deviceready` event before you can add that listener.

Comment: Hi @Eric, thanks for your response. I have tried that too. Check the below code, please. But it did not work.

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        }

Comment: IS the 'deviceready' event firing properly? Can you trace it in the console ?

Comment: Hi @Eric, it is. I put an alert statement there and it is printing the message. But only the backbutton event doesn't get picked up.